# Mrs and Mr His Full Name

Tags: formality, kinship-terms, forms-of-address

My father’s name is Piyush Singh and my mother’s name is Seema Singh. My
question is whether referring to them as *Mrs and Mr Piyush Singh* wrong.

Comment: It's not wrong. By convention, we usually say Mr. & Mrs. Piyush Singh.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your fa­ther were John Smith and your mother were Sarah
Jones, the con­ven­tion you speak of lists the hus­band’s ti­tle
first and uses his name only; you’d say *Mr and Mrs John Smith*
for the mar­ried cou­ple to­gether, and nei­ther *Sarah* nor *Jones*
would be men­tioned in this us­age. *Mrs John Smith* would still
re­fer to Sarah Jones. Think of *Mrs* as read­ing “wife of” here.

This prac­tice in which the wife’s name be­comes com­pletely
in­vis­i­ble is no longer at all so com­monly heard to­day as it
was only a few short gen­er­a­tions ago, but it does still
oc­ca­sion­ally sur­face, par­tic­u­larly with older peo­ple.

Some­times young peo­ple have never have heard of it, or may even
find it trou­bling.  I would not use this style un­less I al­ready
knew it to be the cus­tom in your par­tic­u­lar speech com­mu­nity.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is OK to call them Mr. and Mrs. Piyush Singh, however, there are some (mostly depending on their age) who would find this discriminatory.
I would suggest that you stick with introducing them as; *Piyush and Seema Singh.*
or go fully formal and spell out their full names,  Mr. Piyush Singh and Mrs. Seema Singh.